# selected checkbox values not returned in ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, checkbox

```
var dataArray = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'showdata.php',
    data: {data : dataArray},
    success: function(data) {
        //only the value of last selected checkbox value is returned ,
// but when I alert the dataArray then it shows all values separated with commas.
            alert('response data = ' + data);
        }
    });
```

**showdata.php**

```
$data = ''; 

if (isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $data = $_POST['data'];
}



echo $data;
```

Comment: You probably have no `$data = $_POST['data'];`, for that you would have to do : `data: { data : dataArray },` in your ajax function!

Comment: i have changed data:dataArray to data : {data: dataArray} but still it isn't working

Comment: How many problem do you have with this code?

Comment: @sqlchild that is because your jQuery selector is wrong, use the selector from my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13108807/353710

Comment: Do you have any checked checkboxes to map, and do they actually have a value. You should console.log the dataArray and see what you have. Also try using `print_r($data)` in your PHP function, as you can't really echo an array or object, and the selector would be better with `input[type="checkbox"]:checked` IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$("input:checked")`, not `$('input:checkbox:checked')`.

**Javascript:**

```
var dataArray = {'data': $("input:checked").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get()};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'showdata.php',
    data: dataArray,
    success: function(data) {
        alert('response data = ' + data);
    });
```

**PHP:**

```
$data = ''; 

if (isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $data = implode(', ', $_POST['data']);
}



echo $data;
```

Comment: @sqlchild I added a full example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not comming in your `$_POST` as `data` key but as control names (serialize) or explicit key names given by you (explicit example).

The success callback will get a result of data, what is output by your PHP file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'showdata.php',
    data: $("myformid_in_html").serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        //only the value of last selected checkbox value is returned ,
        // but when I alert the dataArray then it shows all values separated with commas.
        alert('response data = ' + data);
    }
});
```

With the above example, if you put all checkboxes in one form, you could take them all at once.

Or explicitly:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'showdata.php',
    data: {
        mypostvar: "testing_service",
        myotherpostvar: 1
    },
    success: function(data) {
        //only the value of last selected checkbox value is returned ,
        // but when I alert the dataArray then it shows all values separated with commas.
        alert('response data = ' + data);
    }
});
```

Then you have their names inside:

```
$data = ''; 

if (isset($_POST))
{
    $data = $_POST['myformfield_html_name'];
    // or
    $mypostvar = $_POST['mypostvar'];
    $myotherpostvar = $_POST['myotherpostvar'];
}
```

This is the main problem, you are not processing POST data correct. The checkbox is present in POST vars only if it is checked, otherwise you will not find it inside.